# Code behind Bootstrap native classes - where can I see it?

Tags: class, bootstrap-4

I am studying Bootstrap classes to understand better how they work. Documentation is quite detailed and the working of each one is not difficult to understand. However, I would like to "see" which code each one of these classes (or at least the ones I am going to use) carry themselves.

For example `.btn` class, when looked on Chrome DevTools-Source tab shows me that:

```
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: $btn-font-family;
  font-weight: $btn-font-weight;
  color: $body-color;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: $btn-border-width solid transparent;
  @include button-size($btn-padding-y, $btn-padding-x, $btn-font-size, $btn-line-height, $btn-border-radius);
  @include transition($btn-transition);
```

For me, it is useful because I can see all properties and then in some cases, debug something understanding what the native classes may be interacting with things in my code.

I have been looking for a while and went through documentation, but although I find useful information about how to use the classes, I still can't find which code each one of them has inside.

My question: is it possible to see inside these classes (like the `.btn` referred above other than via Developer Tools? If so, is there an index where I can see them all?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the bootstrap source file from https://getbootstrap.com.

Latest : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/download/

The downloaded zip file will contain the compiled files in dist folder. Refer the image below.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to download code on your machine, then you could search for Bootstrap CDN and remove min from the link found:
https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css